# High Stake Gwent Tournament, Cards?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Just won the high stake Gwent tournament in Novigrad and completed the quest. After each match I received a message that I won a new card, but there was nothing on my deck.

I thought that the cards would eventually be added after I completed the whole quest, but still, no cards.

What cards could you win?

Comment: Haven't done that quest yes, but did you cycle through the different card factions in your deck to see if maybe you received a duplicate of one you already had?

Comment: If you already have exact this card, you only see a number on the lower left corner with the # of this cards. They are stacked.

Comment: @PeterCo I thought about this too, but after cycling through my deck I am pretty sure that this wasn't the case. I have some low level cards (1-3) where I'm not sure how much I had, but it is relatively unlikely that I have won cards in this range given the strength of the oponnents.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The 3 'cards' you earn are all leader cards, which is why you don't see any new cards that can be added to your deck.

In particular, these 3:

Emhyr var Emreis, The Relentless

Francesca, Queen of Dol Blathanna

Eredin, Destroyer of Worlds

Comment: AFAIK you can also add leader cards to your deck. That's the way I have added the 'Geralt' or 'Cirilla' card to my deck. Leader cards have some kind of 'burning sun' around their value. Cards for a specific faction show the matching colour in their vertical left-sided banner.

Comment: @PeterCo no, those are hero cards, leader cards are the special activate once per game special effect cards, foltest, emhyr, etc etc

Comment: @z You are right! My bad!